How to resolve Slick Carousel not working after upgrading Drupal from 8.9 to 9.5?
I recently upgraded my Drupal site from version 8.9.6 to 9.5.11, and since the upgrade, the images in the Slick Carousel module are no longer displaying as expected. The Slick Carousel is used for displaying slideshows on my site, but after the update, the feature appears to be broken.
Issue:

Expected behavior: Slick Carousel should load and display a slideshow of images.


Observed behavior: After upgrading, I am seeing an empty carousel instead of the expected slideshow.



However, when I use the Blazy Grid module (which is used for displaying images in a grid view), the images load correctly.
Steps I've taken so far:

I upgraded both Drupal core and the Slick module to the latest versions.

I've tried clearing the cache and rebuilding the site.


Modules in use:

drupal/slick: ^3.0

drupal/slick_views: ^3.0

drupal/slick_extras: ^2.0

drupal/blazy: ^3.0


Composer file details:
Here is the composer.json file with relevant module versions:
{
    "name": "test/project",
    "description": "Drupal is an open source content management platform powering millions of websites and applications.",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "GPL-2.0-or-later",
    "require": {
        "composer/installers": "^1.9",
        "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": "^9.5",
        "drupal/core-project-message": "^9.5",
        "drupal/core-recommended": "^9.5",
        "ext-date": "*",
        "ext-dom": "*",
        "ext-filter": "*",
        "ext-gd": "*",
        "ext-hash": "*",
        "ext-json": "*",
        "ext-pcre": "*",
        "ext-PDO": "*",
        "ext-session": "*",
        "ext-SimpleXML": "*",
        "ext-SPL": "*",
        "ext-tokenizer": "*",
        "ext-xml": "*",
        "php": ">=7.3.0",
        "symfony/console": "^4.4",
        "symfony/dependency-injection": "^4.4",
        "symfony/event-dispatcher": "^4.4",
        "symfony/http-foundation": "^4.4.7",
        "symfony/http-kernel": "^4.4",
        "symfony/mime": "^5.4",
        "symfony/routing": "^4.4",
        "symfony/serializer": "^4.4",
        "symfony/translation": "^4.4",
        "symfony/validator": "^4.4",
        "symfony/process": "^4.4",
        "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "^1.26",
        "symfony/polyfill-php80": "^1.26",
        "symfony/yaml": "^4.4.19",
        "typo3/phar-stream-wrapper": "^3.1.3",
        "twig/twig": "^2.15.3",
        "doctrine/reflection": "^1.2",
        "doctrine/annotations": "^1.13",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.5",
        "symfony-cmf/routing": "^2.3",
        "laminas/laminas-feed": "^2.17",
        "stack/builder": "^1.0",
        "egulias/email-validator": "^2.1.22|^3.2",
        "masterminds/html5": "^2.7",
        "symfony/psr-http-message-bridge": "^2.1",
        "longwave/laminas-diactoros": "^2.14",
        "composer/semver": "^3.3",
        "asm89/stack-cors": "^1.3",
        "pear/archive_tar": "^1.4.14",
        "psr/log": "^1.1",
        "drush/drush": "^11.6",
        "drupal/apigee_edge": "^2.0",
        "drupal/key": "^1.19",
        "drupal/components": "^2.4",
        "drupal/ctools": "3.5",
        "drupal/slick": "^3.0",
        "drupal/modal_blocks": "^2.0",
        "drupal/libraries": "^4.0",
        "drupal/openid_connect": "^1.4",
        "drupal/admin_toolbar": "^3.5",
        "drupal/adminimal_admin_toolbar": "^2.0",
        "drupal/slick_views": "^3.0",
        "drupal/seckit": "^2.0",
        "drupal/entity_reference_revisions": "^1.12",
        "drupal/token": "^1.15",
        "drupal/paragraphs": "^1.17",
        "drupal/field_permissions": "^1.4",
        "drupal/fontawesome": "^2.26",
        "drupal/redirect_after_login": "^3.0",
        "drupal/email_registration": "^1.4",
        "drupal/views_autocomplete_filters": "2.0.1",
        "drupal/smtp": "^1.4",
        "drupal/better_exposed_filters": "^6.0",
        "drupal/git_deploy": "^2.6",
        "drupal/upgrade_status": "^4.3",
        "drupal/block_field": "1.0.0-rc5",
        "drupal/default_content": "2.0.0-alpha3",
        "drupal/slick_extras": "^2.0",
        "laminas/laminas-diactoros": "*",
        "php-http/guzzle6-adapter": "^2.0",
        "ocramius/proxy-manager": "^2.13",
        "jenssegers/proxy": "^3.1",
        "bower-asset/slick-carousel": "^1.8"
    },
    "conflict": {
        "drupal/drupal": "*",
        "drush/drush": "<8.1.10",
        "symfony/http-foundation": "4.4.42"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "autoloader-suffix": "Drupal9",
        "allow-plugins": {
            "composer/installers": true,
            "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": true,
            "drupal/core-project-message": true,
            "dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer": true,
            "php-http/discovery": true
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "installer-paths": {
            "core": [
                "type:drupal-core"
            ],
            "modules/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-module"
            ],
            "profiles/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-profile"
            ],
            "themes/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-theme"
            ],
            "drush/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-drush"
            ],
            "modules/custom/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-custom-module"
            ],
            "themes/custom/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-custom-theme"
            ]
        },
        "drupal-scaffold": {
            "file-mapping": {
                "[project-root]/.editorconfig": "core/assets/scaffold/files/editorconfig",
                "[project-root]/.gitattributes": "core/assets/scaffold/files/gitattributes",
                "[web-root]/.csslintrc": "core/assets/scaffold/files/csslintrc",
                "[web-root]/.eslintignore": "core/assets/scaffold/files/eslintignore",
                "[web-root]/.eslintrc.json": "core/assets/scaffold/files/eslintrc.json",
                "[web-root]/.ht.router.php": "core/assets/scaffold/files/ht.router.php",
                "[web-root]/.htaccess": "core/assets/scaffold/files/htaccess",
                "[web-root]/example.gitignore": "core/assets/scaffold/files/example.gitignore",
                "[web-root]/index.php": "core/assets/scaffold/files/index.php",
                "[web-root]/INSTALL.txt": "core/assets/scaffold/files/drupal.INSTALL.txt",
                "[web-root]/README.md": "core/assets/scaffold/files/drupal.README.md",
                "[web-root]/robots.txt": "core/assets/scaffold/files/robots.txt",
                "[web-root]/update.php": "core/assets/scaffold/files/update.php",
                "[web-root]/web.config": "core/assets/scaffold/files/web.config",
                "[web-root]/sites/README.txt": "core/assets/scaffold/files/sites.README.txt",
                "[web-root]/sites/development.services.yml": "core/assets/scaffold/files/development.services.yml",
                "[web-root]/sites/example.settings.local.php": "core/assets/scaffold/files/example.settings.local.php",
                "[web-root]/sites/example.sites.php": "core/assets/scaffold/files/example.sites.php",
                "[web-root]/sites/default/default.services.yml": "core/assets/scaffold/files/default.services.yml",
                "[web-root]/sites/default/default.settings.php": "core/assets/scaffold/files/default.settings.php",
                "[web-root]/modules/README.txt": "core/assets/scaffold/files/modules.README.txt",
                "[web-root]/profiles/README.txt": "core/assets/scaffold/files/profiles.README.txt",
                "[web-root]/themes/README.txt": "core/assets/scaffold/files/themes.README.txt"
            }
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Proxy\\": "src/Proxy/",
            "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\": "core/lib/Drupal/Core/Composer",
            "Drupal\\Core\\": "core/lib/Drupal/Core",
            "Drupal\\Component\\": "core/lib/Drupal/Component",
            "Drupal\\Driver\\": "../drivers/lib/Drupal/Driver"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "core/lib/Drupal.php",
            "core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php",
            "core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/PhpArrayContainer.php",
            "core/lib/Drupal/Component/FileCache/FileCacheFactory.php",
            "core/lib/Drupal/Component/Utility/Timer.php",
            "core/lib/Drupal/Component/Utility/Unicode.php",
            "core/lib/Drupal/Core/Cache/Cache.php",
            "core/lib/Drupal/Core/Cache/CacheBackendInterface.php",
            "core/lib/Drupal/Core/Cache/CacheTagsChecksumInterface.php",
            "core/lib/Drupal/Core/Cache/CacheTagsChecksumTrait.php",
            "core/lib/Drupal/Core/Cache/CacheTagsInvalidatorInterface.php",
            "core/lib/Drupal/Core/Cache/DatabaseBackend.php",
            "core/lib/Drupal/Core/Cache/DatabaseCacheTagsChecksum.php",
            "core/lib/Drupal/Core/Database/Connection.php",
            "core/lib/Drupal/Core/Database/Database.php",
            "core/lib/Drupal/Core/Database/Statement.php",
            "core/lib/Drupal/Core/Database/StatementInterface.php",
            "core/lib/Drupal/Core/DependencyInjection/Container.php",
            "core/lib/Drupal/Core/DrupalKernel.php",
            "core/lib/Drupal/Core/DrupalKernelInterface.php",
            "core/lib/Drupal/Core/Http/InputBag.php",
            "core/lib/Drupal/Core/Installer/InstallerRedirectTrait.php",
            "core/lib/Drupal/Core/Site/Settings.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "pre-autoload-dump": "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\Composer::preAutoloadDump",
        "post-autoload-dump": "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\Composer::ensureHtaccess",
        "drupal-phpunit-upgrade-check": "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\Composer::upgradePHPUnit",
        "drupal-phpunit-upgrade": "@composer update phpunit/phpunit phpspec/prophecy symfony/yaml --with-dependencies --no-progress",
        "phpcs": "phpcs --standard=core/phpcs.xml.dist --runtime-set installed_paths $($COMPOSER_BINARY config vendor-dir)/drupal/coder/coder_sniffer --",
        "phpcbf": "phpcbf --standard=core/phpcs.xml.dist --runtime-set installed_paths $($COMPOSER_BINARY config vendor-dir)/drupal/coder/coder_sniffer --"
    },
    "repositories": {
        "asset-packagist": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://asset-packagist.org"
        },
        "0": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
        },
        "1":{
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://git.drupalcode.org/project/responsive_carousel.git"
        }
    }
}

Question:
Can anyone help me understand why the Slick Carousel is not working after the upgrade to Drupal 9.5.11? What can I do to fix this issue?

I encounter the same issue when upgrading from Drupal 9 to Drupal 10.
